# Build Keeps Failing on AppVeyor

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, appveyor

I'm trying to build my C# project on AppVeyor because complaining about a missing project. How can I resolve this?

**[AppVeyor Build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/atbyrd/withings-net)**

**[Github Repository](https://github.com/atbyrd/withings.net)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `<NuProjPath>..\packages\NuProj.0.11.14-beta\tools\</NuProjPath>` instead of `<NuProjPath Condition=" '$(NuProjPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\NuProj\</NuProjPath>` [here](https://github.com/atbyrd/Withings.NET/blob/master/Withings.NET.Nuget/Withings.NET.nuproj#L17) according to [NuProj doc](https://github.com/nuproj/nuproj/blob/master/docs/Build.md#hook-your-nuproj-up-to-use-the-new-build-authoring)